# Is it possible to overwrite / block a Javascript code that avoids more than one click per hour?

Tags: javascript, json, greasemonkey, imacros

I've found a voting contest on my country and after realizing that there's people getting a lot of votes on it (like 6k on 4 days), I've been trying to satisfy my curiosity about it without finding a proper answer.

It's a voting contest without any captcha, you just need to click a "Vote" button. But it does have some JS code to avoid more than one vote from the same computer per hour (IP + cookie, as far as I could see), which I think some people managed to avoid, and uses a JSON callback to construct a random confirmation link, which some people might also have managed to construct (which would allow the faster vote possible):

```
http://ws.discoverybrasil.com/curiosity/concurso/altaVoto.php?jsoncallback=jQuery164036090815054306025_1321401398889&video=1327&tema=3&region=2&_=1321401584457
```

Here's the full JS involved on the voting procedure:

```
<script>
var TEMA_ELEGIDO = 0;
var DATOS = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
TEMA_ELEGIDO = getQueryVariable('tema','');
mostrar_tema();
detallar_video();
if(typeof(FB)!='undefined') FB.XFBML.parse(); // lanzo el FB JS SDK (viene en los includes de Discovery).
});
function mostrar_tema(){
$.getJSON(APPSERVER+'/listarTemas.php?jsoncallback=?', function(response){
    if(!response){ alert('Erro no envio de dados. Tente novamente, por favor.'); return };
    if(response.resultado != 1){ alert(response.errormsg); return };
    for(var i in response.lista){
        if(response.lista[i].id == TEMA_ELEGIDO){
            $('#curiosity_tema').html(response.lista[i].titulo);
            TEMA_ELEGIDO = response.lista[i].id;
        }
    }
});
}
function detallar_video(){
var id = getQueryVariable('id');
if(id=='') return;
$.getJSON(APPSERVER+'/detalleContenido.php?jsoncallback=?',{
    'id': id
}, function(response){
    if(!response){ alert('Erro no envio de dados. Tente novamente, por favor.'); return };
    if(response.resultado != 1){
        alert('Error: '+ response.errormsg);
        return;
    }
    DATOS = response;
    $('#curiosity_usuario').html( (response.nombre+' '+response.apellido).replace('<','') );
    $('#curiosity_locacion').html( (response.ciudad+', '+response.pais).replace('<','') );
    /^http\:\/\/www.youtube.com\/.*[\?&]+v[=\/]?([\w\d-_]{11})[^&#]*/.test(response.video_link);
    if(RegExp.$1 == '') /^http\:\/\/youtu.be\/([\w\d-_]{11})/.test(response.video_link);
    var embed = '<object width="854" height="510"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ (RegExp.$1).replace('<','') +'?version=3&rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ (RegExp.$1).replace('<','') +'?version=3&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="854" height="510" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
    $('#curiosity_video').html(embed);
    $('#curiosity_votos').html(response.votos +' votos');
    if(!puede_votar(response.id)) inhabilitar_voto();
});
}
function inhabilitar_voto(){
$('#curiosity a.votar').css({opacity:0.3, cursor:'default'}).html('Votado');
}
function votar(){
if(!puede_votar(DATOS.id)){
    alert('Você só pode votar 1 vez por hora para cada vídeo.');
    return false;
}
$.getJSON(APPSERVER+'/altaVoto.php?jsoncallback=?',{
    'video': DATOS.id,
    'tema': TEMA_ELEGIDO,
    'region': REGION,
}, function(response){
    if(!response){ alert('Erro no envio de dados. Tente novamente, por favor.'); return };
    if(response.resultado != 1){
        if(response.resultado == 2){
            alert('Você só pode votar 1 vez por hora para cada vídeo.');
        }else{
            alert('Error: '+ response.errormsg);
        }
        $('#curiosity a.votar').animate({opacity:1});
        return;
    }
    recordar_voto(DATOS.id);
    inhabilitar_voto();
    $('#curiosity_votos').html( (parseInt(DATOS.votos,10)+1) +' votos' );
});
}
function puede_votar(video_id){
var puede = true;
var ahora = (new Date()).getTime();
var votos = (getCookie('votos')).split('&');
if(votos.length > 0){
    for(var i in votos){
        var pair = votos[i].split('=');
        if(pair.length != 2) continue;
        if(pair[0] != video_id) continue;
        if(parseInt(pair[1]) <= 0) continue;
        if( (1000*pair[1])+3600000 > ahora ){ puede = false; break; }
    }
}
return puede;
}
function recordar_voto(video_id){
var ahora = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
var existente = false;
var votos = (getCookie('votos')).split('&');
if(votos.length > 0){
    for(var i in votos){
        var pair = votos[i].split('=');
        if(pair.length != 2) continue;
        if(pair[0] != video_id) continue;
        existente = true;
        votos[i] = video_id+'='+ahora;
    }
}
if(!existente) votos.push(video_id+'='+ahora);
setCookie('votos', votos.join('&'), 365);
}
function ver_mas(){
location.href='galeria.shtml?tema='+TEMA_ELEGIDO;   
}
</script>
```

So, my question is: am I going nuts or it's possible to block the code that avoids more than one vote per computer per hour or make a random JSON callback like the one used by the website to vote directly (using Greasemonkey or building a random request using Fiddler, maybe?)? Or am I missing something?

I'm not even on the contest, which is finishing by now, but such a high amount of votes really made me curious about it - I really doubt they have 200 or 300 valid and fast proxies to vote per hour using an automation tool (like iMacros).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is this in Spanish *and* Portuguese?

Comment: Because it's made for the Spanish market but translated to Portuguese afterwards. Really looks strange.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the code, and there are basically two barriers to prevent double voting:

1. There's a function called `puede_votar()`, which apparently takes a video id and returns `true` if you haven't voted for that particular video in the last 60 minutes or `false` otherwise. This is relying on cookies, so it can be easily defeated by just clearing your cookies.
2. If you can get past that, it sends a request to `APPSERVER + '/altaVoto.php` with the video id you want to vote on. This will return a response code, possibly a failure. One of these failures is code `2`, which lets you know that you're trying to vote more than once within an hour.

   This most certainly relies on your IP address. And since this is all validated on the server side, your only option would be to get a new IP. So yes, I believe whoever did this just had a lot of time in their hands and a lot of proxies. They could've been using something like [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/).

Comment: Yes, you're right about item 1 - it disables the vote button, so by clearing cookies you enable it again. But can't people make a fake request to the appserver and bypass the IP validation? I'm really intrigued about how people could get so many votes on a faction of time - the only way would have getting 100 fast and reliable proxies and automate the task to make them vote once an hour...

Comment: @WolneyXavier Without the server's validation code, it's really hard to tell. But if you could "fake" a request, it wouldn't be a good validation routine anyways.

Comment: @WolneyXavier I am 99% sure they use the IP address in one way or another, because that's the one thing you can't "fake" - you actually *have to* get a new IP.

Comment: I was thinking about two things:

Comment: I was thinking about two things:

1. The one vote per hour limit is given by the JS, on function puede_votar():

    if( (1000*pair[1])+3600000 > ahora ){ puede = false; break;

So maybe the server just validates the request data, but disabling this part of the code using Greasemonkey is impossible I think.

2. If people could remove everything from the page except the voting JS and button, they could make it way faster to run even on a not so fast proxy. Is there a way to avoid *loading* (and not blocking afterwards, like NoScript for Firefox) parts of the page? This should do the trick.

Comment: @WolneyXavier If you just don't load anything but text (HTML & JS) it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

concerning (response.resultado == 2), my bet is that the server checks for the 1 hour limit, and fails epicly as it uses the cookie info sent by the browser...